# List all environment variable names in busybox

Tags: shell, unix, busybox, env

Environment variables with multiline values may confuse `env`'s output:

```
# export A="B
> C=D
> E=F"
# env
A=B
C=D
E=F
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=\h:\w\$
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

In this case I **can not** just use `awk -F=` to extract all names because it shows wrong names `C` and `E`:

```
# env | awk -F= '{print $1}'
A
C
E
TERM
SHELL
USER
MAIL
PATH
PWD
LANG
PS1
SHLVL
HOME
LOGNAME
_
```

Then I figured out that `env` supports flag `-0` to end each output line with 0 byte rather than newline, so using `sed` I could cut off the values in `bash`:

```
# env -0 | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\([^=]\+\)=\([^\x00]*\)\x00/\1\n/g'
A
TERM
SHELL
USER
MAIL
PATH
PWD
LANG
PS1
SHLVL
HOME
LOGNAME
_
```

But BusyBox's version of `env` [does not support](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#env) flag `-0`. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you open to using another scripting language to do the job, like `python -c 'import os; print "".join(x + "\n" for x in os.environ),'` or `perl -le 'for (keys %ENV) { print $_ }'`, or do you need to confine yourself to a minimal set of shell tools?

Comment: @Celada: With Python it would be too easy :) Here I can use BusyBox only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe not an elegant but working solution. It first extracts all possible names from `env`'s output, then verifies each of them using shell's expansion `${parameter:+word}`. And finally it removes duplicates, since the same variable name could be printed on several lines in `env`'s output (as a real variable name and as a part of some other variable's multiline value):

```
env | awk -F= '/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*=/ {
        if (!system("[ -n \"${" $1 "+y}\" ]")) print $1 }' | sort | uniq
```

PS: The `| sort | uniq` part can be also implemented in `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using linux (I thought busybox ran only on linux, but I may be wrong), `/proc/self/environ` contains a NUL separated environment in the same form as `env -0` gives you. You can replace `env -0 |` with `< /proc/self/environ`.

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\([^=]\+\)=\([^\x00]*\)\x00/\1\n/g' < /proc/self/environ
```

Comment: It's a good idea to parse `/proc/self/environ` but the script for `sed` that you used from my example does not work in busybox's implementation of sed the same way as in regular GNU sed. The first part of sed script `sed -e ':a;N;$!ba'` should accumulate all the lines into one ([seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n#1252191)), but in busybox it also replaces all `\0` characters with `\n`. Try this command in bash and busybox: `echo -ne "A\0B" | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' | hexdump -C`.

Answer (score 1):

This will break if your environment variable *values* contain nulls. But that would also break from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) compatibility.

So it should work.

...unless you expect to encounter environment variable *names* which contain newlines. In that case the newlines will be truncated when they're displayed. However I can't seem to fathom how to create an environment variable with a newline in it in a busybox shell. My local shells balk at it at any rate. So I don't think that would be a big problem. As far as POSIX says, `Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; applications shall tolerate the presence of such names.` so I think stripping them and not erroring-out is *tolerable*.

```sh
# Read our environment; it's delimited by null bytes.
# Remove newlines
# Replace null bytes with newlines
# On each line, grab everything before the first '='
cat /proc/self/environ | tr -d '\n' | tr '\0' '\n' | cut -d '=' -f 1
```